# Close current form if dialog results for dialogbox is cancel

Tags: c#, dialog, inputbox, dialogresult

I have a Form (frmcustlist).
At one time on this list i scan the list using a dataset and check if it now 0 (no customers left).

At this stage i have an input box pop up (dialog) to ask a new customer name.
If they press OK everything is fine.  I also have validation on the box for the input.
However if they press CANCEL, i can get it to escape out of the dialog, but not close frmcustlist that the dialog was called from.

```
using (inputbox ipfirst = new inputbox("Enter Customer First Name:", "", ""))
                    {
                        if (ipfirst.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            newfirstname = ipfirst.answer;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.Close();
                        }

                    }
```

Now, `this.close()` doesn't work at all.. so i used `return;` which stops it going on to ask for the last name and date of birth.. but i want it to stop asking questions (like return) AS WELL as close frmcustlist.
...
Thanks for any advice you can give.

ps. this appears in a few places, but is called in `frmcustlist_load` as well.. i dont know if that is going to make a difference or not!

Comment: Did you show your form with ShowDialog()? then try _this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;_ instead of _this.Close()_

Comment: @Steve. Mate thanks for the that. i KNEW it was basic and i was missing something. 100% Correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer was made by STEVE in comments.
As frmcustlist was called itself as a Dialog, i just ended up having to give that dialog a Cancel result.

Final Code that works:

```
using (inputbox ipfirst = new inputbox("Enter Customer First Name:", "", ""))
                    {
                        if (ipfirst.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            newfirstname = ipfirst.answer;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                            return;
                        }

                    }
```